# jquery filter not giving proper result

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am having a empty `sendStatus[]`. basically i am check the value whether that exist on array while user click on check box. if that's not there i am just add the value with "add+this.value" in case user click on the check box again,

I am checking if the `sendStatus[]` contains the "add+this.value" if that's exist i am removing it and adding a new value as "remove+this.value" , so only i will get a value as "add+this.value"  or "remove+this.value" in the each of my checkboxes.

to do this i used this function but not works:

```
var sendStatus = [];

var clearValues = function(newVal){
            console.log("calling",newVal);

        }

        $("form").on("click", ":checkbox", function(e){

            var el = $(this),parentClass = $(this).parent().hasClass("green"),label = $(this).parent();

            if(!parentClass){
                label.addClass("green");

                sendStatus = $.grep(sendStatus, function(value) {
                    return value != "remove" + el.val();
                });

                if ($.inArray("add" + el.val(), sendStatus) === -1) {
                    sendStatus.push("add" + el.val());
                }

            }else{
                label.toggleClass("red");

                sendStatus = $.grep(sendStatus, function(value) {
                    return value != "add" + el.val();
                });

                if ($.inArray("remove" + el.val(), sendStatus) === -1){
                    sendStatus.push("remove" + el.val());
                }
            }
        console.log(sendStatus);

        })
```

anyone simplify my function and highlight the issue what i am facing.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please would you provide a HTML example of the structure? :checkbox should not be '[type="checkbox"]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is within the :checkbox selector. Is the console.log running? Anyway I think some assignations more will make the code more legible and less error likely. You can try this example solid http://jsfiddle.net/AyjnW/4/ seems working.

```
$("form").on("click",'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){

            var el = $(this),
                label = el.parent(), 
                hasParentClass = label.hasClass("green"),
                elementValue = el.val(),
                removeElementValue = "remove"+ elementValue,
                addElementValue = "add"+ elementValue ;
            if(! hasParentClass ){
                label.removeClass("red").addClass("green");

                sendStatus = $.grep(sendStatus, function(value) {
                    return value != removeElementValue ;
                });

                if ($.inArray(addElementValue , sendStatus) === -1) {
                    sendStatus.push( addElementValue );
                }

            }else{
                label.removeClass("green").addClass("red");

                sendStatus = $.grep(sendStatus, function(value) {
                    return value != addElementValue ;
                });

                if ($.inArray(removeElementValue , sendStatus) === -1){
                    sendStatus.push( removeElementValue );
                }
            }
            console.log(sendStatus);

        }) ;
```

Comment: not working properly, eventhough if i check the value again (turing to green ) result is : ["addAfrikaans"] admin.js:141
["removeAfrikaans"] admin.js:141
["removeAfrikaans"] admin.js:141
["removeAfrikaans"] admin.js:141
["removeAfrikaans"]

Comment: sorry i fixed the code seconds ago, seems that we are not changing the classes well

Comment: i used your updated copy only. i think the issue is here: if(! hasParentClass ){
                label.addClass("green");

                sendStatus = $.grep(sendStatus, function(value) {
                    return value != removeElementValue ;
                });

                if ($.inArray(addElementValue , sendStatus) === -1) {
                    sendStatus.push( addElementValue );
                }

            }

Comment: 100% you are right. very glad you for making me a jsfiddle. very thanks to you. you save a day for me!

Comment: Glad to help, try to use more vars along your code if you do the same assignation twice or more it helps reading.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about `.on()` eventhandler,
Usage:

```
$("selector1").on("click",'selector2', function(e) {...
```

In the selector1 section you have to provide a static node selector, wich not changing at javascript runtime (wich comes from webserver or it is statically in a html document.)
Write the selector the most close to the dinamyc part.
e.g: `$("form table > tbody > tr")`
The selector2 is the dinamyc part of selection, these nodes are created at javascript runtime, they are not in DOM.
So write here your checkboxes or also the td-s (if you have and they are dinamycally created).

```
$("form table > tbody > tr").on("click",'td > input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){ ...
```